# Try block execution in case of VM shutdown

Tags: java, try-catch

I was passing a Java test while I come across the following question:

> Which statement is true?
>
> A. A try statement must have at least one corresponding catch block.
>
> B. Multiple catch statements can catch the same class .
>              of exception more than once.
>
> C. An Error that might be thrown in a method must be
>              declared as thrown by that method, or be handled within that method.
>
> D. Except in case of VM shutdown, if a try block starts to execute, 
>              a corresponding finally block will always start to execute.

I completely don't understand why the answer `D` is true and answer this question by excluding another cases which are obviously false. To find an answer I've read the [JLS section 14.20](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20) but there is no anything which could answer that particular question.

Comment: *A finally clause ensures that the finally block is executed after the try block and any catch block that might be executed, no matter how control leaves the try block or catch block.*

Comment: What support can you find in the JLS for any belief that it might be A B or C?

Comment: @EJP No, A, B and C obviously wrong. It's pretty clear said in the JLS.

Comment: @JBNizet It's ok. But why it won't happens if VM's shuting down?

Comment: Err, *because* the VM is shutting down instead? What's your question?

Comment: @EJP My quiestion is about excpetion in the case D. Why except of VM shutdown?

Comment: Because the VM could never shutdown if code kept executing.

Comment: @EJP VM could shutdown abruptly, due to a critical error. So, if the try block complete normally or abruptly because of throwing an excetion, the finally clause will always being start to execute. There is no another way, is it?

Comment: If the VM is shutting down, it has to terminate threads *whatever* they may be doing. Otherwise it can't shutdown. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: @EJP It's almost obvious. If there was a normative reference descibes that I would be happy...

Comment: The JLS is the normative reference, of course, but don't ask me where.

Comment: It is also possible that the JLS doesn't say this but it is true nevertheless.  I don't understand your need for a normative reference for something that **has to be true** ...

Comment: @StephenC I may seem strange, but yes, I would like to find it. Obviously is that easy to prove, isn't it?

Comment: Well start reading ... 'cos I ain't going to do it for you :-)